Fitting data to a Malthusian exponential model
I have some data from the exponential phase of yeast growth and I want to fit it to a exponential (Malthusian) growth model or curve, so the growth rate (with its error) and any metric of the goodness of fit are calculated. I have been looking through some libraries in R, but most of them perform the fitting using logistic parametric models or linear models.
Does anyone know a library in R that allows me to perform the fitting using the Malthusian growth model?
The data I want to fit has the following form, each column belongs to a replicate and I want to fit each one of them to obtain its individual growth rate.
Time    Lev_NP4 Lev_NP4 Lev_NP4 Lev_NP4
           1       2       3       4
           1       1       1       1
0        6.804  10.242   1.756   8.666
10       6.056  11.887   2.180   9.315
20       7.580  11.681   2.083   10.387
30       8.074  15.904   2.277   11.458
40       7.770  16.321   2.257   13.394
50       8.173  16.958   2.453   14.149
60       7.780  17.233   2.524   15.687
70       8.034  18.534   2.630   16.015
80       9.090  17.923   2.749   15.972
90       3.137  20.148   4.356   17.789
100      3.929  19.205   4.212   17.395
110      3.771  20.506   4.710   18.831
120      3.770  22.257   4.872   14.073
130      4.183  21.989   5.151   12.110
140      3.863  20.855   5.513   12.661
150      4.314  22.081   5.748   14.499
160      5.087  23.145   6.509   14.622
170      5.995  23.185   5.926   14.066
180      6.028  23.847   6.813   14.892
190      5.599  24.778   7.156   14.894
200      6.105  24.550   7.664   15.870
210      6.955  23.927   7.590   13.659
220     10.762  25.918   7.724   15.050
230     12.164  26.139   0.805   15.332
240     10.017  26.603   0.567   17.344


A quick look at the numbers suggests that none of these will be fit very well by the exponential growth assumed in a strictly Malthusian model. Plot your 4 data sets as a function of time and see if exponential growth makes sense.

Thanks for your comment, EdM. Indeed, a Malthusian model is not the best approach for my data. However, I need a simple approach to obtain the growth rate and some goodness-of-fit measure and it was requested to me to perform the fitting in Malthusian.

Logistic growth models looks like they would be more reliable for these data, given the ways that all except the first growth-data column seem to have a plateau at later times. If that's the case, then trying to force the data into an exponential growth won't give you anything reliable. Also, check the data in the last two rows of your third growth-data column; I think there might be misplaced decimal points.

This is just an extension of @EdM 's comment.  Your data has some oddities:

Might there be some typos or parts of columns switched or misplaced decimal points?  Or are there just some sudden drops in growth rate?
